# Standing at the Bima at Kabalas Shabbos and Yekum Purkan

Tags: shabbat, minhag, tefilla, kabbalat-shabbat

In some Shul's that I have prayed I have noticed that during Kabalos Shabbos and Yekum Purkan the Chazzan stands at the Bima instead of the Amud. What is the reason for those Shul's that do it this way?

Comment: Have you prayed in Shul's that the Shazzan was not at the Bima??? I, never!

Comment: @Kouty: Yes I have and do pray in such a Shul every week.

Comment: @kouty Perhaps the terminology confuses you? Here, the bimah refers to the platform used for Torah reading; usually in the middle or back of the shul. The amud is not a platform, but a lectern, usually at the front of the shul, closer to the Aron.

Comment: @DanF no I am not confused, may be that this minhag is the main in Erets Yisraoel, and the minhag of Gershon Gold is Yeke or somewhat other not frequently found in Israel

Comment: @kouty Actually, from what I have seen, this minhag is quite common in Orth. US shuls - almost all that I have been too - both Nusach Ashkenaz & Sefard. Seems to be a bit more universal in Nusach Sefard from what I have seen. The answer, below, seems to summarize why this is minhag for Kabbalat Shabbat. For Yekum Purkun, I surmise the same reason as in the answer - probably mainly for "convenience". Though, perhaps, also since Yekum Purkan is a prayer for Torah scholars it seems to be thematically connected to Torah reading which was done at the bimah.

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi J Sacks in the [Koren Siddur](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xpzEy99oDIYC&dq=koren%20siddur&source=gbs_similarbooks) refers to the gemoro [Shabbos 119a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=119&format=text) where Rabbi Chanino stood on the eve of Shabbos and said, “Come let us go and welcome the Shabbos Queen” etc. The mystics in Safed in the late sixteenth century developed the idea of saying extra psalms to welcome the Shabbos. Rabbi Shlomo Alkabets compose the song, “Lecho Dodi”. This developed into the Kabollas Shabbos service that we now have.

Rabbi Sacks writes that to emphasize the non-statutory character of  Kabollas Shabbos,  the custom in some synagogues is to recite it from the bima and not from the amud (lectern).

There is an extensive discussion of Yekum Purkan in [Rivevos Efraim 6 (455)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&hilite=8c350cd8-188c-4661-a78d-8611ca983a21&st=%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%94&pgnum=573) ; so far I did not find that it discusses saying it from the bimoh.

I suggest it is said from the bimoh for convenience as that is the location of the sefer torah which the chazzan will shortly return to the Ark.